# How can I reprogram my shellcode snippet to avoid null bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, shellcode

I have programmed a piece of x64 linux assembly. All it does is just prints a line "Hello world", that's all. However what I want to do is copy the bytes from it's object file by objdump, so that I can make my own shellcode for my buffer overflow attacks.

The problem I a facing is that the shellcode contains lots of null bytes  and that will terminate the execution of my shellcode.

```
root@kali:~/C scripts/shellcode/Assembly Based Shellcode# cat print.asm
section .text
 
global _start
 
_start:
 
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, message
    mov rdx, 12
    syscall
 
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
 
message:
    db "Hello world", 10
root@kali:~/C scripts/shellcode/Assembly Based Shellcode# nasm -f elf64 print.asm && ld print.o -o print && ./print
Hello world
root@kali:~/C scripts/shellcode/Assembly Based Shellcode# objdump -D print.o
 
print.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
 
 
Disassembly of section .text:
 
0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
   5:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
   a:   48 be 00 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x0,%rsi
  11:   00 00 00
  14:   ba 0c 00 00 00          mov    $0xc,%edx
  19:   0f 05                   syscall
  1b:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
  20:   48 31 ff                xor    %rdi,%rdi
  23:   0f 05                   syscall
 
0000000000000025 <message>:
  25:   48                      rex.W
  26:   65 6c                   gs insb (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  28:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  29:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  2a:   20 77 6f                and    %dh,0x6f(%rdi)
  2d:   72 6c                   jb     9b <message+0x76>
  2f:   64                      fs
  30:   0a                      .byte 0xa
root@kali:~/C scripts/shellcode/Assembly Based Shellcode#
```

I hoped the shellcode would be free from null bytes. However it is not.
Can someone help me and correct my code?

Comment: Use byte loads and find other alternatives to avoid zero bytes. Consult an instruction set reference. E.g. `mov rax, 1` can be written as `xor eax, eax; mov al, 1`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find that set reference. If you do the please give it to me as well. Even this helped me thank you!

Comment: @nltc See [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm).  Another useful reference is http://ref.x86asm.net/ and https://c9x.me/x86/.

Comment: Note that in addition to fixing the NUL bytes, you also need to make your code position independent.  Let me see if I can write an appropriate answer.

Comment: @fuz, yes please! What do you mean by position independent.

Comment: @nltc Position independent means that the address your code is loaded to needs not be known at assembly time.  For example, your `mov rsi, message` is not position independent because it needs to know what absolute address `message` is located at.  To fix this, you need to use something like `lea rsi, [rel message]`.

Comment: Oh thank you! Sorry I am a very beginner to assembly programming and don't know everything about registers, and function like **lea**. Anyways I have tried to remove all most all null bytes, just one is left. I will post the edited code along with the output on pastebin. Here is the link to it: https://pastebin.com/CjUpRzcd. What can I do to remove that remaining null byte

Comment: You can for example add a big offset that you then subtract, e.g. `lea rsi, [rel message+0x11111111];  sub rsi, 0x11111111`

Comment: Thank you so much that helped me! I successfully removed all the null bytes from my shellcode. However, the shellcode is useless I think because when I test it through a C script it doesn't work. Again the everything is posted here: https://pastebin.com/haBhcB4s

Comment: You should use `void*` not `int`. Even the warning says `int` is of the wrong size. Also the `+2` offset may not be correct, you'd have to look at the compiler generated assembly code to check that. To invoke your shellcode the simplest way is to use a function pointer. This happens to work for me: `void **ret = (void**)&ret + 2; *ret = shellcode;`

Comment: @Jester sorry for my late reply. I have been trying out many things, and thank you that code helped me a lot. Now I programmed another assembly code. I tried to remove null bytes from it as well but some are not getting solved. How can I do that? Code and output here:  https://pastebin.com/85zDFeQm

Comment: You put `name` into a separate section. Don't do that, shellcode does not have sections, and especially not `.bss`. Put it at the end and fill it with something other than zeroes, e.g. put 64 `A` letters or something.

Comment: Okay I have done that, but I am encountering another error: https://pastebin.com/2q4S972Y. Since the `**name**` is already filled with 64 **'A'** so when I take input and store it in the `**name**` it gets executed in bash. How can I overcome this now?

Comment: For the standalone version `.text` is not writable (should work in shellcode though). Use `ld -N` for linking. Also, you always print the full 64 bytes even if you did not read that much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confused in assembly and buffer overflows.

I reprogrammed the assembly file like this :

```
section .text

GLOBAL _start

_start:

    xor rax, rax                  ; Clear the RAX register
    push rax                      ; Push the NULL byte [ string terminator ]
    add al, 0x1                   ; RAX = 1, to put the system in sys_write mode
    mov rdi, rax                  ; RDI = 1, to setup the fist parameter for write ( file descriptor to write to ). The integral value for 'stdout' is 1.
    lea rsi, [rel msg+0x41414141] ; Move the relative RIP address of msg to RSI to prepare the string buffer for writing to the stdout. Also add a large 4-byte offset to evade NULL bytes.
    sub rsi, 0x41414141           ; Subtract that large offset to make the RSI point correctly.
    xor rdx, rdx                  ; Empty the 3rd argument for write
    mov dl, 0xc                   ; RDX = 12, 12 ==> string length of msg
    syscall                       ; system call

msg db "Hello world", 0xa
```

### EDIT : As per the discussion in the comment section I have removed the terminating NULL byte

```
section .text

GLOBAL _start

_start:

    push 0x1
    pop rax
    mov rdi, rax
    mov rbx, 'AAAAArld'
    shr rbx, 0x28
    push rbx
    mov rbx, 'Hello wo'
    push rbx
    mov rsi, rsp
    push 0xc
    pop rdx
    syscall
```

and then I compiled the program like this :

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/assembly# nasm -f elf64 main.asm; ld main.o -o main.elf; ./main.elf 
Hello world
Segmentation fault
```

The seg fault really doesn't matter because you want to use this as shellcode for a buffer overflow attack so there is anyway a seg fault there.

Now, extract the bytes from the object code :

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/assembly# for i in $(objdump -D main.o | grep "^ " | cut -f2); do echo -n "\x$i"; done; echo
\x48\x31\xc0\x50\x04\x01\x48\x89\xc7\x48\x8d\x35\x4f\x41\x41\x41\x48\x81\xee\x41\x41\x41\x41\x48\x31\xd2\xb2\x0c\x0f\x05\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x0a
```

**[ OPTION ] : You can test your shellcode before executing it in a memory corruption exploit**

For that just copy the bytes from the above command and make a new C file [ it seems you are confused in the C script as well ]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char shellcode[] = "\x48\x31\xc0\x50\x04\x01\x48\x89\xc7\x48\x8d\x35\x4f\x41\x41\x41\x48\x81\xee\x41\x41\x41\x41\x48\x31\xd2\xb2\x0c\x0f\x05\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x0a";
    int (*ret)() = (int (*)())shellcode;
    // The above line will create an integer pointer ret make it point to a function which doesn't require parameter [ indicated by the () ]. Then it will type casting to cast the shellcode to a function pointer of the same type.
    // So this will essentially cast your shellcode array address to a function pointer which you can later use to call it as a function and execute the code.
    ret(); // Execute the shellcode

}
```

Then compile the program and make sure to make the stack executable otherwise you will end up getting a seg fault here itself and the shellcode will not execute.

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/assembly# gcc -z execstack test.c; ./a.out
Hello world
Segmentation fault
```

From the above code it seems like the shellcode seems to work just fine!

I have tried this on a basic application and it works so your problem should be solved.

Another point to mention is that, only if your executable application [ the one you are going to be exploiting ] uses input methods which stop on a NULL bytes like `strcpy()`, only then you have to remove NULL bytes.

If your executable uses input functions like `gets()` and `fgets()` then you don't need to worry about NULL bytes [ unless you are looking forward for format string vulnerability as well ]
This came from the man page of fgets:

> fgets()  reads  in  at  most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an **EOF or a newline**.  If a newline is
> read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

this clearly means that the NULL bytes shouldn't bother your exploit.

I hope your doubts get cleared!

Comment: Thank you! Your answer seems to clarify my doubts and yes the new assembly file works perfectly! Marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: `push rax` seems pointless.  The `write` system call takes an explicit length, not a 0-terminated string.  So it's unnecessary even if this did happen to get executed with RSP pointing 8 bytes after the end of `msg: db ...`.  There's also several wasted REX prefixes.  Also, you can avoid the `sub rsi, 0x41...` by jumping forward over the string so the `rel32` is negative, with high `0xff` bytes instead of zeros.  (If you want to avoid `0xff` bytes as well, that's a good trick.  Or I guess to make sure the newline is at the end, for fgets with wrong buffer sizes.)

Comment: Also, `push 1` / `pop rax` is a more compact way to set a register to a small immediate constant.  [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981)

Comment: @PeterCordes you are correct the code is a little bit long and somewhat unnecessary as well. But after all, from the question it seems like the user is not very experienced with assembly so I have picked up some points from the other comments to make things easier for the user to understand.

Comment: Yes, I upvoted for the useful comments / text in the rest of the answer.  But especially for an inexperienced user, introducing a `push rax` that wasn't there in the question is just misleading and confusing.  It only 0-terminates `msg` under very specific circumstances which you don't mention, and that isn't needed.

Comment: I agree with you! The NULL terminating string was not required. I was probably thinking about posting a /bin/sh shellcode so I had pushed the NULL byte on the stack. Moreover, this is the first time I have seen a shellcode which prints "Hello World" rather than something which establishes a reverse connection, pops a shell or something like this. The purpose of asking for the shellcode might be to understand how to evade NULL bytes, keeping that in mind I had post the answer! Anyway I have edited the code in the answer and it decreased the shellcode length too, so it should be better!